# Passing a null value in Logic App to an option set field in Dynamics365

Tags: sql, workflow

I am having trouble while passing a null or empty to an option set field in Dynamics365 update a record in Logic App. My purpose of passing a null is to update the previous value in Dynamics365 to empty if a customer has changed/updated a record. For example, I have 2 option set fields in Dynamics 365 for Address Type 1 and Address Type 2. I have multiple options in Address Type one which is a physical address and other options for Address Type 2 which is a Postal Address. If the customer has previously provided Address Type 1 and has now updated new Address which is Address Type 2, I have to empty the Address Type 1 in Dynamics 365 and have to provide a new Address for Address Type 2. 
Creating a new address is fine, but i can not pass a null or empty to an update a record, Logic app picks up the previous value from Dynamics365 if the field is null or empty. 
I shall be grateful for any help or suggestion in this regard.